# Display newly created object in previous page table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an iPhone in the works and I have a question.

I have a home screen that is a table view of Card objects. As shown below.[image]

So for my Card object, I have a card name, card type, and image for the attributes. When you click on "Add new card" it takes you to a new page to let the user specify said attributes. I have all of those set up in my addcardcontroller class. I have the save button set to create a new object when it is clicked. The save method I have so far is shown below

[image]

My question is how to display this newly created object on the home screen's table view.

If any code is needed just ask and i'll post it. I don't like to post unnecessary code snippets.

Comment: Why do not pass an instance of Card Object create in TableView Controller and fill it in AddController ?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? That's what I want to do, I'm just not sure of the syntax in objective-C and xcode. I'm not sure how to use AddController to fill in variables in TableViewController.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `FirstViewControlle.h` define one `NSMutableArray` like:

```
@property (nonautomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableArray;
```

IN `FirstViewController.m` synthesize it like:

```
@synthesize tableArray;
```

In `saveNewCard` method of `AddNewCardViewController` add this lines at last:

```
-(IBAction)saveNewCard:(id)sender{

  .....

  .....

  FirstViewController *firstView = (FirstViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2];

[firstView.tableArray addObject:newCard];

}
```

In `viewWillAppear` method of `FirstViewController` also add `[myTableView reload];`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to happen. That code you added to the saveCard method is a little hazy to me. I'm not exactly sure what's going on there. But it works. If you wouldn't mind pointing me to documentation to explain or give me a quick description that would be awesome, but not required, thanks man!

Comment: Actually self.navigationController.viewControllers returns one array of viewControllers pushed till now.
So last pushed ViewController is AddNewCardViewController in your case.
And we want to access tableArray which is of FirstViewController which is pushed just before the last object in navigationController so we have to give count-2 to get this object.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. I guess I need to think about the layers of controllers more. But seeing this syntax will help tremendously. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

Step 1 :
 In AddController declare a public property of Card type

```
@interface AddController : UIViewController
...
@property (nonatomic;retain) Card* newAddedCard;
...
@end
```

In SaveNewCard IBAction replace allocation code by the property

```
....
   self.newAddedCard.name= cardName;
   self.newAddedCard.icon = chosenIcon;
   self.newAddedCard.cardType = carTypeString;
....
```

Step 2 : 
When the TableViewController present AddController set newAddedCard with new instance of Card Object

```
.....
     Card* addCard = [[Card alloc] init];
      //You must retain addCard object on TableViewController in a ivar
      AddController.newAddedCard = addCard;
.....
```

Comment: Does this help with memory or something? Or is this just a semantics type of thing?